# Mecanim alternative to curves

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the Mecanim animation system right now and don't have the pro license so using the 'curves' option isn't possible. Is there an alternative solution to using curves to do something like reduce gravity's effect on a character during an animation, or modify a character's collider height and position during an animation?